# How to pass argument values into argparse with Python, to connect to an API?

Tags: python, api, parsing, arguments

In the process of learning scripting with Python and I have been trying to understand how to connect to an API, specifically this one: https://leagueapps.com/api-documentation/.  I was given a sample Python script from the company to connect with and use their API as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Example of exporting registrations, members, and transactions with batched
# results.  A limited number of results are returned in each response.  It can
# vary based on the type, but is generally around 1000 records.

# ubuntu 16.04: sudo apt install python-jwt python-crypto python-requests
# untested: pip install pyjwt crypto requests2

import argparse
import time
import random

import jwt
import requests

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--site-id', type=int, required=True)
parser.add_argument('--client-id', required=True, help='client id for site.  Probably the same as the certificate filename basename')
parser.add_argument('--pem-file', required=True, help='filename for certificate key in PEM format')
parser.add_argument('--type', required=True, choices=['registrations-2','members-2','transactions-2', 'accountingCodes'], help='type of records to export')
parser.add_argument('--domain', default='leagueapps.io')
parser.add_argument('--auth', default='https://auth.leagueapps.io')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.auth:
    print("using auth server {}".format(args.auth))
    auth_host=args.auth

if args.domain == 'lapps-local.io':
    # for local testing the Google ESP isn't HTTPS
    admin_host='http://admin.{}:8082'.format(args.domain)
else:
    admin_host='https://admin.{}'.format(args.domain)

site_id=args.site_id
record_type=args.type

# Make a request to the OAuth 2 token endpoint with a JWT assertion to get an
# access_token
def request_access_token(auth_host, client_id, pem_file):
    with open(pem_file, 'r') as f:
        key = f.read()

    now = int(time.time())

    claims = {
            'aud': 'https://auth.leagueapps.io/v2/auth/token',
            'iss': client_id,
            'sub': client_id,
            'iat': now,
            'exp': now + 300
            }

    assertion = jwt.encode(claims, key, algorithm='RS256')

    auth_url = '{}/v2/auth/token'.format(auth_host)

    response = requests.post(auth_url,
            data={ 'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
                'assertion': assertion })

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()['access_token']
    else:
        print('failed to get access_token: ({}) {}'.format(response.status_code, response.text))
        return None

# Calculate seconds to sleep between retries.
#
# slot_time is amount of time to for each slot and is multiplied by the slot
# random calculated slot to get the total sleep time.
#
# max_slots can be used to put an upper bound on the sleep time
def exponential_backoff(attempts, slot_time = 1, max_slots = 0):
    if max_slots > 0:
        attempts = min(attempts, max_slots)

    return random.randint(0, 2 ** attempts - 1) * slot_time


# Initialize the last-updated and last-id query parameters to be used between
# requests.  These should be updated after processing each batch of responses
# to get more results.
last_updated = 0
last_id = 0

access_token = None
batch_count = 0

# Maximum number of retries for a request
max_attempts=5
attempts=0
while attempts < max_attempts:
    attempts += 1

    # Get an access_token if necessary
    if access_token is None:
        print('requesting access token: {} {}'.format(args.client_id, args.pem_file))
        access_token = request_access_token(auth_host, args.client_id, args.pem_file)
        if access_token is None:
            break

    print('access token: {}'.format(access_token))

    params={'last-updated': last_updated, 'last-id': last_id}
    # set the access token in the request header
    headers={ 'authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token) }

    response = requests.get('{}/v2/sites/{}/export/{}'.format(admin_host, site_id, record_type), params=params, headers=headers)

    # access_token is invalid, clear so next pass through the loop will get a new one
    if response.status_code == 401:
        print('error({}): {}'.format(response.status_code, response.text))
        access_token = None
        # immediately retry since it should get a new access token
        continue

    # Request can be retried, sleep before retrying
    if response.status_code == 429 or response.status_code >= 500:
        # sleep an exponential back-off amount of time
        wait_seconds = exponential_backoff(attempts, 1.42, 5)
        print('retry in {} on error status ({}): {}'.format(wait_seconds, response.status_code, response.reason))
        time.sleep(wait_seconds)
        continue

    # error on request that can't be retried
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print('unexpected error ({}): {}'.format(response.status_code, response.reason))
        # reasonably some sort of coding error and retry is likely to fail
        break

    # get the actual response JSON data
    records = response.json()

    
    # No more records, exit.
    if (len(records) == 0):
        print('done.')
        break

    batch_count += 1

    # successful request, reset retry attempts
    attempts = 0

    # process the result records and do useful things with them
    print('processing batch {}, {} records'.format(batch_count, len(records)))
    printFile = open("records.json","w+")
    def remove_uni(s):
        s2 = s.replace("u'", "'")
        s2 = s2.replace('u"', '"')
        return s2
    printFile.write("[")
    for record in records:
        #print(remove_uni(str(record)));
        #print('record id: {}, {}'.format(record['id'], record['lastUpdated']))
        # track last_updated and last_id so next request will fetch more records
        last_updated = record['lastUpdated']
        last_id = record['id']
        printFile.write(remove_uni(str(record)) + ",")

    printFile.write("]")
    printFile.close()
```

I can't seem to get this code to work and the error I get is:

```
usage: Main [-h] --site-id SITE_ID --client-id CLIENT_ID --pem-file PEM_FILE
            --type {registrations-2,members-2,transactions-2,accountingCodes}
            [--domain DOMAIN] [--auth AUTH]
Main: error: the following arguments are required: --site-id, --client-id, --pem-file, --type
```

I have tried to figure out how to pass values for the arguments, but it's not clear to me where they get placed in this script and can't find an answer after many searches and reading tutorials.

Can someone show me how to solve this or point to articles that will help me understand enough to do so?  I wondered if I should learn what all of this sample code means in detail first, but for sake of getting results was going to focus on just getting it working...if you think I should take the former approach versus the later or vice versa, I'd love to know that too given I'm a beginner.

Thanks!

Gabe

Comment: Can you show how you're running the script? The usage message that's printed is telling you how to do so and which arguments are missing.

Comment: Hey! I'm using PyCharm and running the script in PyCharm in a file called Main in venv->bin folder.

What's not clear to me is where exactly do I enter argument values?  I thought the parser.add_argument() function called several times in the script does that already?

Comment: I don't have PyCharm, but there should be an option to set the command line arguments somewhere. Failing that, you could just run the script on the command line and pass the arguments. No, argparse is only setting up what parameters are valid, required, etc.

Comment: Ok thank you, it's making more sense now!  Is argparse something that should not run inside a script every time then?  I thought command line arguments that the script is calling, would be inside the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

So with the help of @ndc85430 I found the solution:

Because argparse enables your script to run with argument values entered via the command line, when you run your script you run your script in an editor you need to ensure the editor is feeding those values somehow.  In PyCharm, you go to Run -> Edit configurations, then enter the values you want in your run configuration by entering them in the Parameters field.   For example for the case I posted above, it would be --site-id (type SITE_ID here) --client-id (type CLIENT_ID here) --pem-file (type the PEM_FILE name if in the same directory or put directory location here to PEM_FILE) --type (type the type here for the option you selected out of the options you defined in argparse.

Once you enter your parameters and give the configuration an appropriate name, save it down.  Then in Pycharm you'll have the option to run that configuration when you run and test your script.